# Windows Azure Toolkit for android

Tags: android, azure

I read [Windows Azure Toolkit for Android](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/08/31/now-available-windows-azure-toolkit-for-android.aspx) to understand how I can connect Android with Windows Azure. I still unclear after I read the blog since they didnt provide the basic tutorial or sample on how we can connect. Does anyone manage to connect android to Windows Azure. Appreciate if you advice me on how or where I can find start up package to connect Windows Azure with Android. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this; http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/08/windows-azure-toolkits-for-devices-now-with-android/, from the actual developer who built the toolkit for Android.

it is my understanding that the toolkit that you can download includes a sample application that you can open, and test on the Android emulator.

"The library project includes the full source code to the storage client and authentication implementations.

Once you configure your workspace in Eclipse, you can run the simple sample application within the Android emulato"

if that doesn't help, let me know and I will find somebody that can help you.

Comment: I downloaded the tool kit from https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Toolkits/wa-toolkit-android, but once I extract the zip file and import to Eclipse it throws erros...
1.Project 'Access Control for Android Sample App' is missing required library: '/Access Control for Android/bin/access control for android.jar'
2.Project 'Windows Azure Storage For Android Sample App' is missing required source folder: 'gen' Windows Azure Storage For Android Sample App..

Comment: I apologise for the troubles with this Toolkit. My best advice would be to reach out to the team on Github and report this error to them.